# Showing the Closure on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I'm Trying to Practice scope closure in JS and I'm Quite stuck on implementing the scope closure on Html Page. 
It is a quite simple code I did But it is just doesn't work.
The main idea of this code is to use the function "increase" inside the button event "onclick" and then show the result on the div:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict'

    var showIncrease = document.getElementById("increase").innerHTML;



    this.increase= function (strat) {
        return function () {
            start++;
            return start;
        }
    }

    var inc = increase(0);

    showIncrease = inc;


}).apply(this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
   

    <button onclick="inc()">increase</button>


    <div id="increase"></div>


    <script src="timer.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inc` function in your example is a local variable of the function scope. You can use it inside of that function, like you're using the `start` inside `increase`, but you can't access it from outside of the function scope. The onclick from the button will try to access it in the global scope (window), so it can't find the function. It can, however, find `increase()`.

If you, change the `var inc = increase(0);` to `this.inc = increase(0);`, the `inc` variable will be in the global scope (the window object). This will make the onclick able to find it.

And even then it won't show the result inside the div, you're just assigning the variable `showIncrease` with the function `inc`, it won't update the html that way.

To update the contents of the div you could wrap your `inc` function, to increase and update the contents:

```
var divIncrease = document.getElementById("increase");
var inc = increase(0);

this.incAndShow = function () {
    var result = inc();
    divIncrease.innerHTML = result;
}
```

And in your html call that function instead:

```
<button onclick="incAndShow()">increase</button>
```

An example at https://jsfiddle.net/0kvbL3o1/

Comment: It did finally Work, Thank you